# XML Sitemap Generator and 404 problem

Tags: plugins, server, configuration, google-xml-sitemaps

I am using yahoo hosting, wordpress 3.0.1 and [Google XML Sitemaps (Wordpress Plugin)](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/google-sitemap-generator/) 3.2.4.

This plugin generates sitemap.xml and notify all webmasters successfully.

I am able to see sitemap.xml through FTP but the problem is whenever i open the link http://blog.example.com/sitemap.xml, it's showing 404 error.

Comment: Do you have any extra code in your .htaccess beyond the basics generated by WordPress?

Comment: I a using yahoo web hosting so i don't have access to .htaccess file.

Comment: Please check if that XML file you can see via FTP is actually inside the right directory. If not, that might be the cause of your problem. In any case please provide more information: Are you using pretty permalinks? Which file-permissions need to be set on files via FTP so that they can be requested via HTTP? Which file-permissions are set on the XML file? And who is owning that file? Under which user does your PHP get's executed.

Comment: i can see the file using FTP. I am using yahoo webhosting in which i have installed wordpress. and in wordpress i have installed the xml sitemap generator.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same issue with one of my customers I'm consulting with. We've done 100's of WordPress installs on our own or other dedicated machines with no issues.

Some hosting companies have issues with WordPress plugins due to the path structure in some hosting environments.

I can FTP into root directory, delete Yahoo's preloaded sitemap.xml file and load a custom generated file, but it will always display the original Yahoo file. This tells me it's pulling the file from another location possibly.

I'll be contacting Yahoo this week to see if they have any insight. On my last call with them, they say they do not provide any support for WordPress plugins which is odd since they preload a bunch of customized Yahoo plugins.

Yahoo also does some other odd things:

1) You can only use permalinks structure that Yahoo allows, you cannot modify.
2) Yahoo provide SEO plugin, but you have no access to it. We have not worked with enough Yahoo installs, but I'm guessing you can uninstall a Yahoo preloaded pluging and manually install the plugin yourself.

Comment: Tried this tonight: use custom location and absolute path>>>#   Absolute or relative path to the sitemap file, including name.
Example: /var/www/htdocs/wordpress/sitemap.xml
# Complete URL to the sitemap file, including name.
Example: http://www.yourdomain.com/sitemap.xml - If you don't see your file immediately, wait an hour or two then check it again. Sitemap generator is working fine for me now putting sitemap.xml in root directory.